# How To parseFloat() strings coming from an Observable?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an issue trying to convert text to number for geoloc coordinates.
My model is: A site with Id etc... and an Array of points as a property. I decided not to create a relationship between site and points.

So in my code:
**points** is declared like this:

```js
points: Array<any> = [];
```

**rectangles** is declared like this (an Array of Arrays):

```js
rectangles: Array<Array<LatLngLiteral>> = [];
```

I am "looping" on **sites** for a particular **customer** and am building the Array called **rectangles** to show it on google map. rectangle is composed by as many as Arrays that sites are coming from the DB. Here I have two sites and the rectangle Array is:

```
rectangles : [[
[
   {"lat":44.841225,"lng":-0.580036},
   {"lat":44.842236,"lng":-0.64696},
   {"lat":44.805615,"lng":-0.63084}
],
[
   {"lat":44.819868,"lng":-0.582811},
   {"lat":44.853709,"lng":-0.483573},
   {"lat":44.80696,"lng":-0.53299},
   {"lat":44.80696,"lng":-0.629078}
]]]
```

The code to retrieve it is:

```
this.customerApi.getSites(this.currentUser.id)
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.sites = response;
    this.rectangles.push(this.sites.map(s => s.points));
  });
}
```

Sites is like:

```
sites : 
[
    {
    "siteName":"Site de Marseille",
    "siteAdress1":"rue de blabla",
    "siteAddress2":"string",
    "siteCodPost":"13010",
    "siteTown":"Marseille",
    "points":
       [
         {"lat":44.841225,"lng":-0.580036},
         {"lat":44.842236,"lng":-0.64696},
         {"lat":44.805615,"lng":-0.63084}
        ],
    "id":"5d0ce7c4a06b07213a87a753", 
    "companyId":"5cd430745304a21b9464a219",
    "customerId":"5cd430c65304a21b9464a21a"`
    }
    ,
    {
"siteName":"Site de Bordeaux",
"siteAdress1":"rue de la  Garonne",
"siteAddress2":"string",
"siteCodPost":"31000",
"siteTown":"Bordeau    x",
"points":
    [
        {"lat":44.819868,"lng":-0.582811},
        {"lat":44.853709,"lng":-0.483573},
        {"lat":44.80696,"lng":-0.53299},
        {"lat":44.80696,"lng":-0.629078}
    ],
"id":"5d0cf65fa06b07213a87a754",
"companyId":"5cd430745304a21b9464a219",
"customerId":"5cd430c65304a21b9464a21a"}]
```

[image]

The format of my **rectangles** array is good as another array like this with value hand written in the code show the rectangle on Google Map. Except maybe the number of square brackets ...

I think this comes from data format.

So I tried: `points: Array<LatLngLiteral> = [];` and it does not work.

I have no idea where I could use the parseFloat() method to try (if necessary).

Does any one have an precious idea to help me please?

Comment: You already have numbers. As a useful reminder, strings are usually between quotes, in your case it's not : those are numbers !

Comment: ok thanks. I also noticed that rectangles has too many square brackets. I do not know where this comes from.

Comment: Without a [mcve] I can't really tell you.

Comment: my problem is to know why the push (.map ...) is generating an extra square bracket. Here is the definition: https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/interfaces/latlngliteral

Comment: According the code you provide, there is not reason to have an extra square bracket. Check my [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f1vltw)...

Comment: yes this is how it should be. Nevertheless I still have an extra square bracket coming from the ... push ....

Comment: harcoding values and commenting the push method: rectangles : [[{"lat":44.841225,"lng":-0.580036},{"lat":44.842236,"lng":-0.64696},{"lat":44.805615,"lng":-0.63084}],[{"lat":44.819868,"lng":-0.582811},{"lat":44.853709,"lng":-0.483573},{"lat":44.80696,"lng":-0.53299},{"lat":44.80696,"lng":-0.629078}]] there are only two square brackets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195580/discussion-between-youri-and-philippe-correges).

Comment: commenting out the push keeping hard coded values: the push adds an array of arrays: rectangles : [[{"lat":44.841225,"lng":-0.580036},{"lat":44.842236,"lng":-0.64696},{"lat":44.805615,"lng":-0.63084}],[{"lat":44.819868,"lng":-0.582811},{"lat":44.853709,"lng":-0.483573},{"lat":44.80696,"lng":-0.53299},{"lat":44.80696,"lng":-0.629078}],[[{"lat":44.841225,"lng":-0.580036},{"lat":44.842236,"lng":-0.64696},{"lat":44.805615,"lng":-0.63084}],[{"lat":44.819868,"lng":-0.582811},{"lat":44.853709,"lng":-0.483573},{"lat":44.80696,"lng":-0.53299},{"lat":44.80696,"lng":-0.629078}]]]

Comment: So it adds an array of arrays whilst it should only add arrays ...

Comment: How to chat please?

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

There is no `float` type in typescript so what you can do is to create a function that check for the content of any string and then convert it if this is a float as below:

```
getFloatValue(val) {
    if (val.indexOf('.') > -1) {
        try {
            eval(val);
            return parseFloat(val);
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    }
    return val;
}
```

You can use this with each property of your object like this:

```
let lat = getFloatValue(rectangle[0].lat);
```